# To find which Transaction Manager gets loaded among multiple transaction managers when @transactional is called

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

Have some legacy code having transaction management defined in 2 configuration files as

```
1.  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager1" mode="aspectj" /> 
2. <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager2" mode="aspectj" />
```

Have a method as follows

```
@Transactional
public void addDoc(param doc) throws customException {
}
```

Know Transaction qualifier should have been used here. But it has not been used.
**Is there any way to find which transaction-manager is being used when @Transactional gets called**. Are there any JAR classes which can show this.

Thanks